# Boost/python.hpp is not correctly linked when using CMake and Conan

Tags: c++, cmake, boost-python, conan

I am trying to use conan for the very first time to try to retrieve `Boost.Python` and start a project using it. I have having issues that  once I open my visual studio solution I get a red underline for `#include <boost/python.hpp>` and it will not compile.

I have a following build structure,

`src/main.cpp` is the following,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/python.hpp>  

using namespace boost::python;  

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(myMath)

find_package(Boost)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}     
    src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}     
    Boost::python)
```

Finally my `conanfile.txt` is,

```
[requires]
boost/1.83.0

[options]
boost*:without_python=False

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

Running  `conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing` will retrieve Boost correctly and also find `Boost::python`. I build my solution using,

`cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 19 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake`.

Looking inside the `conan_toolchain.cmake`  I can see the following line,

`list(PREPEND CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "C:/Users/Name/.conan2/p/b/boost4b77a2a85257b/p/include"`

I can verify that `python.hpp` exists at
`C:/Users/Name/.conan2/p/b/boost4b77a2a85257b/p/include/boost/python.hpp`.

From this component alone I am unsure why it is not linking.

From all of this I do not understand why my visual studio cannot correctly link to `boost/python.hpp` once I open my solution. Any help is appreciated. I am also receiving a linking error trying to find ZLIB when following the conan2 tutorial. I have followed all the steps and made sure the variables are all set from my previous question.

The desired folder structure is,

```
BoostExample
    - Build
        - CMake
            - CMake output is here (soltuion etc)
        - (Build file from conan are put here)
    - Src
        main.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - conanfile.txt
```

[image]

The exact error when trying to compile from the CLI is,

```
C:/Users/Michael/.conan2/p/b/boost4b77a2a85257b/p/include\boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp(57,11): fatal  error C108
3: Cannot open include file: 'pyconfig.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\C++\BoostExample\build\C
Make\myMath.vcxproj]
```

When opening the solution file, a red squiggly is under the include and it will not compile there. I also receive the same problem when following the tutorial using ZLIB, however that seems to compile when using the CLI commands, but still does not link correctly.

Comment: It is not clear if it doesn't compile because it cannot find the header (you comment it cannot correctly link). The contents of the ``conan_toolchain.cmake`` are not the most important ones, but the contents of the conan generated ``boost-config.cmake`` that should be the ones found by CMake. It might be worth to submit the above, together with the full log to https://github.com/conan-io/conan as a github issue.

Comment: @drodri Following the tutorial I can get it to compile and run the executable using the CLI commands, however opening the solution I still get a red underline and it is not linking to ZLIB. However in this case even using the CLI commands I still get a `/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp(57,11): fatal  error C108
3: Cannot open include file: 'pyconfig.h':`.

Comment: The file `pyconfig.h`, which is **actually** missed, comes from the Python, not from the Boost. I would expect `Boost::python` target to have appropriate dependency on the Python library. But most of examples about using Boost python aside from `find_package(Boost)` perform `find_package(Python COMPONENTS Development)` (or its alternatives).

Comment: in order to use `find_package` I need to have the config file, where would this be retrieved from, another conan dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely `find_package(Boost)` doesn't look for python, this is the case even when not using conan, you need to manually bring in python yourself:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(myMath)

find_package(Boost)
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}     
    main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}     
    Boost::python Boost::python Python3::Python)
```

Comment: Interesting, but for `find_package` to work I need the associated config files for Python3. Where can I find these if this is not retrieved from conan?

Comment: They're built into cmake https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html, it should just work, i didn't have to do any additional configuration to get this example to build